# Replacement for sun-dried tomato pesto sauce?

Tags: tomatoes, blender, dairy-free

I'm crazy about the [Barilla sun-dried tomato pesto](https://www.barilla.com/en-us/products/sauces/sun-dried-tomato-pesto).  However, the local store where I was buying it has dropped it.  Can I get a similar effect by putting in a blender or food processor the sun-dried tomatoes that come in oil in a jar?

Note, I have not found another dairy-free brand of sun-dried tomato pesto.  (I'm allergic to dairy.)  The Barilla version seems to be the only one.  (I am in the U.S.)

---

I see that there is a close vote.  Feedback would be helpful so I can recast the question or avoid asking off-topic in future.

Comment: Ingredients list for it is : "DICED TOMATOES, SUNFLOWER OIL, ONIONS, SUN-DRIED TOMATOES, BASIL, SALT, GARLIC, SUGAR, OREGANO, CAPERS"

Comment: Not sure how much storage space you have, but you could trying asking the store if they would order you a case of the sauce. Jarred sauce would keep for a long time. Stores only have so much shelf space and they tend to stock items that turn over. If they don't sell much they will switch to something else.

Comment: You can also amazon it if you want to buy online

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use chopped up sun dried tomatoes, either in oil or dry stored.

For the dry sun-dried tomatoes, you should re-hydrated them a little bit in warm water before mixing them up.

As always, you will need to experiment with the ingredient ratios to get the flavour you like best.

Comment: What do you think about the blender or food processor?

Comment: food processor, you do not want to turn it into a paste.